# Google Analytics Data Client for Java - io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found

Tags: java, google-analytics-api, liferay-7

I'm trying to implement Analytics Data Client API for Java in Liferay 7.3 version but It cant work.

```
InputStream fileInputStream = GoogleAnalyticsReportsGA4Portlet.class.getResourceAsStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fileInputStream);
        BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
                BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
                        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credential))
                        .build();

        try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {...}
```

When BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(...) is when have the next issue:

io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:45)
at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:351)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.(ChannelPool.java:105)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:83)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:236)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:230)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:201)
at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.stub.GrpcBetaAnalyticsDataStub.create(GrpcBetaAnalyticsDataStub.java:149)
at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.stub.BetaAnalyticsDataStubSettings.createStub(BetaAnalyticsDataStubSettings.java:161)
at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.(BetaAnalyticsDataClient.java:172)
at com.google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(BetaAnalyticsDataClient.java:154)

Comment: Have you tried "Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded"?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
This is the code that work:

```
BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings = BetaAnalyticsDataSettings
            .newHttpJsonBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credential))
            .build();
```

Only I had to put ".newHttpJsonBuilder()"